# Modx. Как передать аргумент в tpl в getImageList?

Tags: modx, migx

Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать аргумент в чанк в getImageList, инлайн не работает, хочу что-то вроде этого:

```
[[getImageList?
  &tvname=`e_migx`
  &tpl=`@INLINE [[tpl_e? &active=true]]`
]]
```

Цель - сделать первый элемент активным, а остальные нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь уже имеющимися плейсхолдерами `getImageList`
Вам подойдет:

```
[[+_first]] — вернет 1, если это первая запись
```

Дполнительно:

```
[[+fieldname]] — любое поле из конфигурации MIGX или из переданных параметров в сниппет
[[+idx]] — порядковый номер, начиная с 1
[[+_first]] — вернет 1, если это первая запись
[[+_last]] — вернет 1, если это последняя запись
[[+_alt]] — вернет 1, если это четная запись
[[+total]] — общее число элементов (можно изменить через &totalVar)
[[+property.name]] — выведет параметр с именем &name=`` в вызове getImageList. 

Например, при вызове:

[[getImageList? &tvname=`slider` &tpl=`@CODE: [[+image]]`]]

плейсхолдер [[+property.tvname]] будет иметь значение «slider».
```

Документация на дополнение: https://docs.modx.com/current/ru/index

Comment: сделала через индекс, внутри тпл, но как аргумент передать в тпл внутри getimagelist так и не поняла

Comment: Так последний параметр `property.name` для этого, в вашем случае добавляете в вызов `getImageList` параметр `&active=true` а внутри tpl это будет `[[+property.active]]` и он будет равен `true` но для первого элемента вам достаточно уже имеющегося `[[+_first]]`